# Selecting a row in Gridview and deleting it - Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, gridview, delete-row

I have a gridview which populates its data from a MS Access Database. I have enabled the "Selecting" on the gridview, and have created a delete button. I would like to select a row on the gridview and delete the data from the gridview as well as the database when the delete button is pressed. Below is my attempted code, but its not working.

Error that I am getting is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the line of code where it says, "myDataSet.Tables["Users"].Rows[i].Delete();"

Webservice method:
//Modifies the datbase

```
[WebMethod]
public string DatabaseUserModify(DataSet myDataset) 
{ 
 string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|/studentdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"; 
 OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database); 
 OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Users", 
myConn); 
OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter); 
 builder.QuotePrefix = "["; 
 builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"; 
 myConn.Open(); 
 myDataAdapter.Update(myDataset, "Forum"); 
 myConn.Close(); 
return "done"; 
}
```

Website:

```
protected void DeleteButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Service myService = new Service();
    myDataSet = myService.AdminGetUserTable();

    int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    myDataSet.Tables["Users"].Rows[i].Delete();//This is where I am getting error

    GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    myService.DatabaseUserModify(myDataSet);
}
```

Comment: Should be obvious. Set a breakpoint on that line and when invoked, check what's null. You should be able to sort it out after that. Try and let us know.

Comment: I think you would be getting the myDataSet as null on the postback. Is it? Confirm it by step into the code (breakpoint). As ASP.NET page is stateless, it would be loosing myDataSet object value.

Comment: @MSI I have set the breakpoint and its giving me null on "myDataSet.Tables["Users"]"

Comment: @Ali.NET giving me null on myDataSet.Tables["Users"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *myDataSet* is probably being lost after the postback. You must have to save the *myDataSet* in page's *ViewState* in order to retain it's value across postbacks. Like this:

```
    public DataSet myDataSet 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return ViewState["myDataSet"] != null ? (DataSet)ViewState["myDataSet"] : null; 
        }
        set 
        {
            ViewState["myDataSet"] = value;
        }
    }
```

***But, it is a worst idea to save large data/objects in a ViewState.***